# How to check if the file is an image

Tags: java, image, exception

I want to check if the file passed is an image and if not I want to show a message indicating that the file is not an image .

```
try{
    Image img = ImageIO.read(new File(name));
}catch(IOException ex)
{
    valid=false;
    System.out.println("The file" + name + "could not be opened, it is not an image");
}
```

When the file (referenced by `name`) is not an image valid is not set to `false`, why is this happening?
Should I change the type of the exception? I have read about the try-catch, and as I understand if ImageIO.read fails and the type of the exception is IOException contents of catch block will be executed. So why its not executed ?

Is there is any other way to check if the file is an image??

Comment: @Gerret thanks I searched but I didn't see this post

Comment: This link will be useful to you :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643228/test-if-file-is-an-image

Comment: I posted the same link 22 mins ago ;)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

According to the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.File%29), read returns `null` if the file can not be read as an image.

> If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the resulting
>   stream, `null` is returned.

So, your code should be the following:

```
try {
    Image image = ImageIO.read(new File(name));
    if (image == null) {
        valid = false;
        System.out.println("The file"+name+"could not be opened , it is not an image");
    }
} catch(IOException ex) {
    valid = false;
    System.out.println("The file"+name+"could not be opened , an error occurred.");
}
```

Comment: I think this is the right approach but it's no error free. Take a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079754/convert-and-display-image-from-byte-array?noredirect=1#comment26495118_18079754). In this case `ImageIO` couldn't read image files even when those files actually were images.

Answer (score 5):

According to API `ImageIO.read(...)` returns `null` if no registered `ImageReader` able to read the specified file is found, so you can simply test returned result for `null`.

Comment: Brent Worden was faster. But you are right :)

Comment: that is why I voted up both answers and accepted his answer ^^

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get the extension:

```
String extension = "";

int i = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
if (i > 0) {
    extension = fileName.substring(i+1);
}
```

And check the conditions as u want

```
if(extension=="jpg"){
//your code
}
```

and so on

Comment: What if i change the extension of an image from .jpeg to .mpeg?

Comment: I am not sure this will always works. An extension can be changed or can be absent.

Comment: What if there is no extension at all? Shouldn't that cause a problem here? As far as I know, the correct way is to check for the mime type.

Comment: Usually images do not a have extensions like .mpeg or .wmv

Comment: but it do have extension like .jpeg or .png or .gif etc

Comment: Use `extension.equals("")` instead of `==`. see this question: [**How do I compare strings in Java?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: @Azad: You are right...