# embed files into java executable file

Tags: java

Normally we write code to read a data file such as an image. In my case I want to produce a single *.class file which contains the information of some images, so that when I execute the java file it will display the images without dependency on any other files. Appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: If you are happy to have it in the same `.jar` file put it as a resource.

Comment: @Henry it wants it to be embedded in the produced .class file.

Comment: @LppEdd I know. But this is not be the "normal way" of doing it. Also almost all non-trivial Java programs have more than one `.class` file anyhow.

Comment: @Henry I know I know, no sane developer would use resources this way. I think it is more of a challenge.

Comment: In case this can be an option, you may have your class draw the image by itself using `Graphics` objects and methods like`drawLine`, etc.. . I remember having done that once, in an application that created its icons by itself .

Answer (score 1):

You can store the images as base 64 so they will be part of the file, see: [Java - Convert image to Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226046/java-convert-image-to-base64) for more details.

this way the image will be constant in the class and therfore will be compiled inside it

Answer (score 0):

Never done this, but an image is a series of bytes. You could store the bytes in a byte array and use it to "recreate" it.

See [Convert and display image from byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079754/convert-and-display-image-from-byte-array)